# Javascript getelementbyid error -- uncaught referenceerror

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving the following message when running the Javascript below:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: videoembed is not defined**

I created the function below. I am not that experienced with javascript so I am no doubt missing something elementary, but I have debugged this for about 30 minutes and I've reached a point where I need help.

See it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/4zWhP/4/

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the help, here is a working, final version: http://jsfiddle.net/4zWhP/7/

```
<a class="pull-left" href="javascript:videoembed('dcFtnvC82dE','45687');"><small><i class="fa fa-fw fa-youtube-play"></i> Play Video</small></a>
<div id="video_45687"></div>

function videoembed(ytlink,uid) {
    var ytlink = ytlink;
    var uid = uid;
    ytembed = "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/"+ytlink+" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe></div>";
    document.getElementById("video_"+uid+).innerHTML = ytembed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of a syntax error in your code (extra `+` plus sign):

```
// ---------------------------------v
document.getElementById("video_"+uid+).innerHTML = ytembed;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4zWhP/5/

Comment: Thank you! I've used the JS console with Chrome and I never received a syntax error. Any other recommendations to debug simple things like that?

Comment: @Astralis Nothing special actually, as in my Chrome console I receive `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` error.

Comment: Ah, it so makes sense. I should have noticed it meant exactly what it said. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

it's a syntax error: Remove extra `+` sign

```
document.getElementById("video_"+uid).innerHTML = ytembed;
                      --------------^----
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4zWhP/6/)

Comment: Thank you! Very fast eye! The js chrome console never threw a synax error.

Comment: @Astralis You can identify it by clicking the error in console, But that seems to be an error for the syntax as it can be easily identified so keep in mind that if there is `+` sign for concatenation there has to be a string followed by it! and in your case it hasn't :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a class="pull-left" onclick="videoembed('dcFtnvC82dE','45687');">
    <small>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-youtube-play"></i> Play Video
    </small>
</a>
<div id="video_45687"></div>
<script>
    function videoembed(ytlink,uid) {
        ytembed = "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/"+ytlink+" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen><\/iframe></div>";
        var elem = document.getElementById("video_"+uid);
        elem.innerHTML = ytembed;
    }
</script>
```